# Passing pointer to member function parameter into template argument

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, delegates, member

How can i forward a member function pointer into a template type parameter. I have the following code.

```
template <typename T, typename ret, typename ...params>
class lol2
{
    template <ret(T::*memfn)(params...)>
    void boo() 
    {
        /* some code here */ 
    }
};

template<typename T, typename ret, typename ... params>
void foo(ret(T::*memfn)(params...))
{
    auto test = lol2<T, ret, params...>{};
    test.boo<memfn>(); /*error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token */
}
```

I need to be able to forward the member function pointer into the template argument. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Should it be `template <ret(T::*memfn)(params...)>` instead of `template <ret(DerivedType::*memfn)(params...)>`? There is no `DerivedType` defined anywhere in the example.

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks for spotting it. Made the correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context where it is called `boo` is a dependent name. You'll need to use

```
test.template boo<memfn>();
```

Of course, this won't work, either when `memfn` is a run-time value: it can only work if it is a constant experession. If you need to deal with a run-time value you'll need to pass the argument somehow. It could become a member of `lol2` or an additional argument to `boo()`.

You'll also need to fix the definition of `lol2` and use `T` insted if `DerivedType`.

Comment: @TartanLlarma: yes - just spotted that after posting (and commented on that in the answer).

Comment: Thanks so much. I totally new to C++. Correct me if I'm wrong, does this mean that either the type signature be const as follows,
void foo(ret(T::*memfn)(params...) const)

because I still need to deduce it as a template argument. I guess I could make it work with macros. Either way this is fantastic, Thanks!

Comment: @user2379758: although the `const` is legal, it means something different (it declares the member function being passed to be a `const` member, i.e., making it applicable to a `const` object). Using a function parameter as a template argument won't work: template parameters are determined at compile-time while function parameter values are only known at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Have in mind that member functions in order to be callable must be bind with an object.
Thus, you would have somehow to pass an object of the class at the point of call. Furthermore, you have to forward the member function pointer:

```
template <typename T, typename ret, typename ...params>
class lol2 {
  T &obj;
public:
  lol2(T &obj_) : obj(obj_) {}
  void boo(ret(T::*memfn)(params...), params&&... pars) { 
    (obj.*memfn)(std::forward<params>(pars)...);
  }
};

template<typename T, typename ret, typename ... params>
void foo(T &obj, ret(T::*memfn)(params...), params&&... pars) {
  auto test = lol2<T, ret, params...>(obj);
  test.boo(memfn, std::forward<params>(pars)...);  
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55fd6a319e77af97)

Comment: Forwarding in `boo` is not perfect forwarding, indeed. Am I wrong?